# Deleting duplicate copy of cURL command line application and point the system to only one copy of it

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, homebrew

I recently updated my copy of cURL via Homebrew, which it put in `/usr/local/Cellar/curl` (v7.80.0). I also have an older version of it (7.43.0), which is located at `/usr/bin/curl`. This is the version I execute without specifying the path (as per `which curl`). I'm using bash shell.

It seems it's not a good idea to simply remove `/usr/bin/curl` and place a symbolic link from `/usr/bin/curl` to `/usr/local/Cellar/curl`. So how do I tell the system to use the newer version located in `/usr/local/Cellar/curl`?

Do I need to update environment settings to ensure curl gets found?
Is there a way to "uninstall" the old copy of curl in `/usr/bin/curl`?

Answer (score 2):

Executing `brew info curl` shows the following:

```
curl: stable 7.81.0 (bottled), HEAD [keg-only]
Get a file from an HTTP, HTTPS or FTP server
https://curl.se
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/curl.rb
License: curl
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✘
Required: brotli ✔, libidn2 ✘, libnghttp2 ✔, libssh2 ✘, openldap ✘, openssl@1.1 ✔, rtmpdump ✘, zstd ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
curl is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

==> Analytics
install: 171,673 (30 days), 491,229 (90 days), 1,633,820 (365 days)
install-on-request: 73,776 (30 days), 211,410 (90 days), 817,005 (365 days)
build-error: 76 (30 days)
```

The text under Caveats section reads:

> curl is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
> because macOS already provides this software and installing another
> version in parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

That explains why you are unable to use a more *recent* version of cURL despite installing it.

The older version that you are referring to is the version that comes pre-installed with macOS.

You cannot simply delete or temper with the system installed version of cURL as the same is protected by the macOS System Integrity Protection subsystem. You can learn more about System Integrity Protection here:

- https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204899

You can execute the Homebrew installed version of cURL via the absolute path as follows:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.80.0/bin/curl
```

or, update your PATH environment variable by running the following command line to make the Homebrew installed version of cURL take preference over the macOS installed version:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.81.0/bin:$PATH
```